# How do I get to which window I am hovering over?

Tags: 11.04, unity

In Ubuntu 11.04, in workspace when I press super W shortcut, I get to multiple I opened in a workspace, when I am moving over from one window to other, how do I know the title very clearly

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you could set up the scale/scale add-ons plugin (by installing the compiz extra plugins package and ccsm - compiz config settings manager) to show a customizable window title across the window (you could change font size, and the behaviour -- show title only on window you are currently hovering over or all the windows. Unfortunately, the option doesn't seem to work in the latest version, for reasons unknown, I clearly remember using it before. I suggest you try it yourself because it might be an isolated incident only affecting me.

Here's a preview of the plugin window in CCSM, yet it doesn't work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55sk4.png